# how registers stock binary values?

Tags: memory, binary, processor

Just a matter of curiosity, how binary values are stuffed in processor memories ? is it the same way as the ram does ? what is that ? magnetism ?
Well I'd like to know since I picture signals has an electric flow, if the latter is true how could a flow be stocked within a memory space ? thanks for the head-ups !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latch_(electronics).